# jMock Mocking Classes and Interface

Tags: java, mocking, jmock

I was experimenting jMock as my mocking framework for my project. I came into a situation where I need to mock both a class and an interface. I used the `ClassImposteriser.INSTANCE` to initiate the impostor of the context.

Supposing a class `Validator` and an interface `Person` to mock. When I was going to mock the Interface `Person`, I ran to a problem `NoClassFoundDefError`. When I mocked the class `Validator`, there was no problem.

I need both that class and interface but I can't solve the problem.
Please HELP.

Code Example:

Mockery

> `private Mockery context = new JUnit4Mockery() {{ setImposteriser(ClassImposteriser.Class) }};`

Class :

> `private Validator validator;`

Interface :

> `private Person person;`

Inside Test Method

> `validator = context.Mock(Validator.class);` ----> Working
>
> `person = context.Mock(Person.class);` ----> `NoClassFoundDefError`

Comment: please add code examples to make your question clearer. Perhaps I can help you..

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The code as you present it won't compile (it should be ClassImposteriser.INSTANCE).  The example code below seems to work fine.  Perhaps you could provide some more details?

```
public class Example {
    private Mockery context = new JUnit4Mockery() {
    {
        setImposteriser(ClassImposteriser.INSTANCE);
    }
    };

    @Test
    public void testStuff() {
    Validator validator = context.mock(Validator.class);
    Person person = context.mock(Person.class);

    // do some stuff...
    }

    public static interface Person {
    }

    public static class Validator {
    }
}
```

Comment: NOTE: As of jmock 2.11.0, ClassImposteriser has been deprecated in favor of the oddly-named ByteBuddyClassImposteriser. https://github.com/jmock-developers/jmock-library/blob/master/jmock-legacy/src/main/java/org/jmock/lib/legacy/ClassImposteriser.java

Answer (score 0):

Since this question keeps coming up in the searches, and it's a bit outdated, I've decided to contribute with an answer.

As @Ogre Psalm33 and @bm212 have already said in their answer and comment, in order to generate a mock for a concrete class, we need to configure the `Mockery`'s `Imposteriser` with a `ClassImposteriser.INSTANCE` for versions of JMock prior to 2.11.0, while with a `ByteBuddyClassImposteriser.INSTANCE` from JMock 2.11.0 on.

> As of jmock 2.11.0, `ClassImposteriser` has been deprecated in favor of the oddly-named `ByteBuddyClassImposteriser`. https://github.com/jmock-developers/jmock-library/blob/master/jmock-legacy/src/main/java/org/jmock/lib/legacy/ClassImposteriser.java

However, the `ClassImposteriser.INSTANCE` configuration (JMock < 2.11.0) works only up to JDK 15. While, the solution with `ByteBuddyClassImposteriser.INSTANCE` (JMock >= 2.11.0) works for every JDK*, as long as the [byte-buddy dependency](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/net.bytebuddy/byte-buddy) is included when using JDKs 14 and above according to the comment section of the issue [#204](https://github.com/jmock-developers/jmock-library/issues/204#issuecomment-1850096058) in the official JMock's repository on GitHub.

However, despite what is reported in the issues of the official repository, from my tests emerged that when using `ByteBuddyClassImposteriser.INSTANCE` **without** the byte-buddy dependency with JDKs 12 and 13, an `IllegaleStateException` is thrown with the message "No code generation strategy available", **making this dependency actually necessary from JDK 12 instead of 14.**

*All my JMock tests have been conducted from JDK 8 to 21. At the moment of writing this answer, JDK 21 is the latest one.

---

### Pre JMock 2.11.0

##### Supported up to JDK 15

```
Mockery context = new JUnit5Mockery() {
   {
      setImposteriser(ClassImposteriser.INSTANCE);
   }
};
```

### From JMock 2.11.0

##### Supported up to JDK 21 with byte-buddy dependency

##### Supported up to JDK 11 without byte-buddy dependency

```
Mockery context = new JUnit5Mockery() {
   {
      setImposteriser(ByteBuddyClassImposteriser.INSTANCE);
   }
};
```

---

### Example mocking the concrete class InputStream

The following example has been implemented using JDK 21, but can be reproduced with any other combination of JDKs and `Mockery` configurations described above.

##### ConnectionFactory.java

```
public interface ConnectionFactory {
    InputStream getData() throws Exception;
}
```

##### WebClient.java

```
public class WebClient {
    public String getContent(ConnectionFactory connectionFactory) {
        String workingContent;
        StringBuffer content = new StringBuffer();
        try (InputStream is = connectionFactory.getData()) {
            int count;
            while (-1 != (count = is.read())) {
                content.append(new String(Character.toChars(count)));
            }
            workingContent = content.toString();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            workingContent = null;
        }
        return workingContent;
    }
}
```

##### TestWebClientJMock.java

```
import org.jmock.Expectations;
import org.jmock.Mockery;
import org.jmock.imposters.ByteBuddyClassImposteriser;
import org.jmock.junit5.JUnit5Mockery;
import org.junit.jupiter.api.Test;
import org.junit.jupiter.api.extension.RegisterExtension;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;

import static org.junit.jupiter.api.Assertions.assertEquals;
import static org.junit.jupiter.api.Assertions.assertNull;

public class TestWebClientJMock {
    @RegisterExtension
    Mockery context = new JUnit5Mockery() {
        {
            setImposteriser(ByteBuddyClassImposteriser.INSTANCE);
        }
    };

    @Test
    public void testGetContentOk() throws Exception {
        ConnectionFactory mockConnFactory = context.mock(ConnectionFactory.class);
        InputStream mockInputStream = context.mock(InputStream.class);

        context.checking(new Expectations() {
            {
                oneOf(mockConnFactory).getData();
                will(returnValue(mockInputStream));

                atLeast(1).of(mockInputStream).read();
                will(onConsecutiveCalls(
                        returnValue(Integer.valueOf('W')),
                        returnValue(Integer.valueOf('o')),
                        returnValue(Integer.valueOf('r')),
                        returnValue(Integer.valueOf('k')),
                        returnValue(Integer.valueOf('s')),
                        returnValue(Integer.valueOf('!')),
                        returnValue(-1)));

                oneOf(mockInputStream).close();
            }
        });

        WebClient client = new WebClient();
        String workingContent = client.getContent(mockConnFactory);

        assertEquals("Works!", workingContent);
    }

    @Test
    public void testGetContentCannotCloseInputStream() throws Exception {
        ConnectionFactory mockConnFactory = context.mock(ConnectionFactory.class);
        InputStream mockInputStream = context.mock(InputStream.class);

        context.checking(new Expectations() {
            {
                oneOf(mockConnFactory).getData();
                will(returnValue(mockInputStream));

                oneOf(mockInputStream).read();
                will(returnValue(-1));

                oneOf(mockInputStream).close();
                will(throwException(new IOException("cannot close")));
            }
        });

        WebClient client = new WebClient();
        String workingContent = client.getContent(mockConnFactory);

        assertNull(workingContent);
    }
}
```

##### pom.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>org.example</groupId>
    <artifactId>JMockTestClass</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>

    <properties>
        <maven.compiler.source>21</maven.compiler.source>
        <maven.compiler.target>21</maven.compiler.target>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.junit.jupiter</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit-jupiter-api</artifactId>
            <version>5.9.2</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.junit.jupiter</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit-jupiter-engine</artifactId>
            <version>5.9.2</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jmock</groupId>
            <artifactId>jmock-junit5</artifactId>
            <version>2.11.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jmock</groupId>
            <artifactId>jmock-legacy</artifactId>
            <version>2.11.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>net.bytebuddy</groupId>
            <artifactId>byte-buddy</artifactId>
            <version>1.14.10</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</project>
```