# Jmocking classes

Tags: testing, jmock

I ran into this question that has been asked 3 years ago:

[jMock Mocking Classes and Interface](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/968171/jmock-mocking-classes-and-interface)

My question is how can you jmock classes that are not interfaces? As far as I know, class jmocking can happen only with @Mock anotation, represented in JMock version which to this day is not yet stable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

jMock cookbook has an entry for you.

Here is the link: http://www.jmock.org/mocking-classes.html

Comment: Can you set expectations for those too?

Comment: Yes, you should be able to. Based on the code snippets from the link I gave you, you'll see that `context.checking(...` is available to you.

Comment: Uh. i tried to mock static class. That's different story. But this works otherwise.